# Parse multiple instances of a string using ReadP

Tags: parsing, haskell, text-parsing, string-parsing

Problem Statement: Parse the string `"AB"` in `"ABCDFGABIJABGHA"`

Constraint: Using `ReadP`

Expected Solution : `(["AB","AB","AB"],"whatever is left")`

Attempt:

```
getAll :: ReadP a -> ReadP [a]
getAll p = many loop
  where
    loop = p <|> (get >> loop)

readP_to_S (getAll $ string "AB") "ABCDFGABIJABGHA"
[([],"ABCDFGABIJABGHA"),(["AB"],"CDFGABIJABGHA"),(["AB","AB"],"IJABGHA"),(["AB"],"IJABGHA"),(["AB","AB","AB"],"GHA"),(["AB","AB"],"GHA"),(["AB","AB"],"GHA"),(["AB"],"GHA")]
```

I wanted the last state to be `(["AB","AB","AB"],"GHA")`. Is it possible to do the same using `ReadP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a symmetric choice with `<|>`. If you want your parser to match all the `p`s without exception use the provided left-biased choice: [`<++`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#v:-60--43--43-).

```
getAll :: ReadP a -> ReadP [a]
getAll p = many loop
  where
    loop = p <++ (get >> loop)
```